# Replace case statement with Hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to replace `case` statement in ruby with `Hash`. But the Hash seems to call the default value first every time when I try to lookup for other keys in the hash.

```
def perform_operation_one
  puts 'Performing operation ONE'
end

def perform_operation_two
  puts 'Performing operation TWO'
end

def exit_program
  puts 'Program is exiting now'
  exit(0)
end

def perform_operation(operation_code)
  case operation_code
    when 1
      perform_operation_one
    when 2
      perform_operation_two
    else
      exit_program
  end
end
```

I replaced the above `case` statement with the `Hash`

```
def perform_operation(operation_code)
  operations = Hash.new exit_program    #Default value if no operation is present in operations corresponding to operation_code key
  operations[1] = perform_operation_one
  operations[2] = perform_operation_two
  operations[operation_code]
end
```

Now when I execute following:

```
perform_operation(2)
```

Expected Output:

```
Performing operation TWO
```

Current Output:

```
Program is exiting now
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to replace the `case` statement? It looks much cleaner IMO (although I'd write each `when` in a single line, i.e. `when 1 then perform_operation_one`).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line:

```
operations = Hash.new exit_program
```

evaluates `exit_program` right when that line of code is reached.

What you're trying to do here is pass a method as a value, which you can do, but it's not quite as simple as say Javascript, where just typing the method name would suffice. Remember, in Ruby parenthesis are optional for method calls, so your default value ends up being the *return value* of the `exit_program` (in this case, that's undefined since the program exits).

You can lambda-fy your methods (let them be passed as values) like so:

```
def perform_operation(operation_code)
  operations = Hash.new(-> { exit_program })
  operations[1] = -> { input_from_file }
  operations[2] = -> { input_from_console }
  operations[operation_code].call
end
```

I'm basically wrapping every method in `-> { }` (an anonymous function / lambda). The `.call` is there because you specify that it's time to evaluate the lambda (calling the method).

Rather than using `-> { }` you could also use `method(:exit_program)`, `method(:input_from_file)`, etc. It converts to a proc but it's basically the same thing, you still use `.call`.

Comment: Just for fun, you could also use `Hash.new { exit_program }`

Answer (score 1):

First, I think your `case` is fine. It's readable and might be less bug-prone than a solution with a hash.

With a hash, you could write :

```
def perform_operation(operation_code)
  operations = { 1 => :perform_operation_one, 2 => :perform_operation_two }
  operations.default = :exit_program
  send(operations[operation_code])
end
```

Since `send` doesn't care about method privacy, you could set `exit_program`, `perform_operation_{one,two}` as private. As a matter of fact, they're already private when defined in `main`.